# Access Environment variable in extensions

Tags: swiftui

In a `View` I can access the environment variables with the `@Environment` property wrapper like this:

```
struct MyView: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: Color

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .foregroundColor(self.colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
    }
}
```

In an extension, this is not possible, because I cannot put variables to an `extension`. How can I access the `@Environment` values in an extension, for example if I want to extend `Color`?

Until now I found out, that I can use `Environment` with the `wrappedValue` property like this:

```
extension Color {
    static var darkModeText: Color {
        if Environment(\.colorScheme).wrappedValue == .light {
            return .black
        } else {
            return .white
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that this doesn't gets updated and always contains `.light`. I also tried using `@Environment` as a global variable, but this is (not yet) supported by property wrappers.

Comment: Environment values are injected in View after View creation. In the way you try to use it there are no creation, so no injection - it is misconception. Would you describe your final goal? Where/how are you going to use it? Probably it should be rethink to view modifier or custom view builder, etc.

Comment: I just want to have the possibility to write `Color.darkModeText`, so that I can access it everywhere in my project without write `colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white`

Comment: Then just define such color in Assets catalog and it will work automatically for you.

Comment: Oh stupid me, I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Just found out some hours ago, that you can do this in the assets catalog. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a similar issue. I want to have a "contrastColor" to the current accentColor. So I cannot use the "static" xcassets solution... Any clues, or does anyone know how the original "accentColor" works under the hood?